# unexpected Goods recieved - area of Concern?

Tags: scams

I have received a parcel today of a fake pair of Ray Ban sunglasses.Posted from a Chinese company. A receipt was included . The receipt listed my correct phone number, incorrect details of my credit card and the cost was listed as $198 US.I have checked all of my bank statements and cannot find any cost that correlates. Is this some type of new scam? The receipt is listed for a company as BayBan.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Received a package but didn't order it](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/114928/received-a-package-but-didnt-order-it)

Comment: Also https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131097/unexpected-goods-delivery-is-this-a-scam-and-what-kind-of-scam

Comment: I had almost the same question 2 1/2 years ago. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131097/unexpected-goods-delivery-is-this-a-scam-and-what-kind-of-scam  Most likely to get a good review. Nothing else happened. Also listed a credit card number that supposedly paid which I didn’t know.

Answer (score 6):

One common scheme is that they need positive reviews, usually on Amazon marketplace.

So they take a bunch of random addresses, place an order through the marketplace for one of their products to be shipped to that address, wait for it to show up as delivered, and then enter a 5 star review.

Since there was an actual payment and an actual delivery, it will show up as a “verified” review, and contribute to better ratings and better position in search results, which should help them sell a lot more products and cover the negligible cost of some fake stuff and extremely cheap postage.

Using addresses or randomly chosen people will help defeating anti-fraud systems which would scream if they only shipped items to themselves (in China…).

If that is what is happening, there is no specific financial risk for you. It just means your name+address+phone number are listed somewhere (like the phone directory…).

There is possibly an extremely marginal risk that customs could have found about the package containing a fake and come bother you saying you imported fake stuff, but I’m not even sure they do that in the US at all (and in countries where they actually do it, they are extremely unlikely to do that for a one-off low value item).

If they used someone else’s card rather than a legitimate card, then there would be a risk that the police could come knocking on your door saying you bought the item using stolen card details. I have no idea how they go around checks on the issuing country of credit cards, but I would be surprised if they used stolen cards, as a high number of chargebacks would probably be an even bigger red flag, so I would think they instead use other (legitimate) means of payment.

The final risk is that if you use the product you received it may completely fail any safety rules, so just don’t.

If you **really** want to be on the safe side, go to the police and tell them you receive this while you didn’t order it. You probably can’t file a complaint about this (you didn’t suffer any damages), but they should be able to record this and/or provide a document stating you advised them. This of course by itself isn’t enough to exonerate you, but it will be positive indication in case this ever goes somewhere. Tell them to keep the item as evidence or destroy it (them, not you).

Note that I am considering only the “fake reviews” case here. If indeed someone used your address to ship stuff bought with stolen card details, expecting to be able to retrieve it before you, the risk would be higher, but it seems unlikely for a pair of cheap fake sunglasses. The advice would be the same though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a new scam, it is an old one.

Here's how it works. They steal someone's credit card and order things online to be shipped to someone else's address, in this case yours. Then a porch pirate may come by since they know all the tracking information and steal the package. You may have gotten to the package before they did.

If they bought items with a stolen credit card and had it shipped to their own address the police could easily find them.

Comment: the corollary being that the OP may be contacted by the police regarding a order passed to their address using a stolen credit card

Comment: But a *single* pair of fake Ray Bans?

Comment: This isn't the only possibility; it could be fake reviews or similar. See the answers I linked in the comments. In any case: if you didn't order it, you are under no obligation to return it or pay for it; you can use it, or throw it out, or whatever seems appropriate.

Comment: @RonJohn - A $200 pair of Ray Bans

Comment: @JohnFx *fake* RayBams, according to OP.

Comment: Genuine BayRans, they go well with my Rolodex watch.